# Not getting expected results for smaller case of Project Euler 145

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am work on [Project Euler 145](http://projecteuler.net/problem=145) which says:

> Some positive integers n have the property that the sum `[ n + reverse(n) ]` consists entirely of odd (decimal) digits. For instance, `36 + 63 = 99` and `409 + 904 = 1313`. We will call such numbers reversible; so 36, 63, 409, and 904 are reversible. Leading zeroes are not allowed in either n or reverse(n).
>
> There are 120 reversible numbers below one-thousand.
>
> How many reversible numbers are there below one-billion (10**9)?

I am trying the following code (and instead of using 10^9 I am using 10 to check if the result (which should be zero) is happening:

```
def check(x):
    y = int(str(x)[::-1]) #x backwards
    #add the rev number to the original number (convert them to a list)
    xy = list(str(x+y))
    #a list of even digits.
    evens = ['0', '2', '4', '6', '8']
    #check if the number has any digits using intersection method.
    intersect = set(xy).intersection(set(evens))
    if not intersect:
        #if there was no intersection the digits must be all odd.
        return True
    return False

def firstCheck(x):
    if (int(str(x)[:1])+(x%10))%2 == 0:
        #See if first number and last number of x make an even number.
        return False
    return True

def solve():
    L = range(1, 10) #Make a list of 10
    for x in L:
        if firstCheck(x) == False:
            #This quickly gets rid of some elements, not all, but some.
            L.remove(x)
    for x in L:
        if check(x) == False:
            #This should get rid of all the elements.
            L.remove(x)
    #what is remaining should be the number of "reversible" numbers.
    #So return the length of the list.
    return len(L)

print solve()
```

It works in two parts: In the method `solve` there is a `firstCheck` and `check` the first check is to eliminate some numbers quickly (so when I make a 10^9 size list I can free some RAM). The second check is the one that gets rid of all the numbers supposedly that are not "reversible numbers". In the first check I just see if the first and last digit make an even number, and eliminate that number. In the check method I reverse the number, add the two numbers together and make them into a list, then check if it intersects a list of evens, if it does eliminate it from the list. The resulting list should be the number of elements that are "reversible" numbers so I take the list and return its length. For `range(1,10)` I get 2 as the result (as opposed to the desired zero). And the numbers it doesn't eliminate [4,8] and I can't seem to find out why.

Comment: Notes: 1. You can avoid any space concerns by *counting* instead of managing lists, that's also faster. 2. This approach is slow and doesn't scale well, by analysing the conditions you can get a solution that returns the answer instantaneously even for bounds like 10^20.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems.

First, you (twice) modify a list that you're iterating over:

```
for x in L:
    if firstCheck(x) == False:
        #This quickly gets rid of some elements, not all, but some.
        L.remove(x)
```

This will lead to unexpected and hard-to-predict behaviour.  Either iterate over a copy of the list or simply filter using a list comprehension:

```
L = [x for x in L if firstCheck(x)]
```

etc.

Second, you're not checking to eliminate any leading zeros, so check(10) is True when it should be False.  After fixing those, your code seems to work:

```
>>> len(solve(10))
0
>>> len(solve(1000))
120
```

[I just added a parameter to choose the range.]

Comment: @anon: "Leading zeroes are not allowed in either n or reverse(n)."

Comment: Oh, wait, I misread, I thought that it was saying that like ther were leading zeros they wouldn't be allowed so eliminate the zeros and then do it...

Comment: PS: "something == False" is much less pythonic than "not something".

Answer (score 0):

Java solution and it takes 3 minutes

```
public class Euler145 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  int i, j, add, convert, count = 0;
  String get;
  StringBuilder rev;

 for ( i=0; i <= 1000000000; i++) {
        get = "" + i;
        rev = new StringBuilder(get);
        rev.reverse():
        convert = Integer.parseInt(rev.toString());
        add = convert + i;

        if (add % 2 != 0)  {

            while (add > 0)  {
                 j = add % 10;

                 if (j == 1 || j == 3 || j == 5 || j == 7 || j == 9)  {
                    add /= 10;
                    String leadZero = "" + i;
                    if (j == 0 && !leadZero.endsWith("0"))  {
                        count++;
                    }
                   }  else  {
                     break;
                 }
            }
        }
   }
      System.out.println(count);
 }
}
```

Comment: This question is about Python